# Rabin Hash Functions - FAST Implementation in Java

Tags: java, hash, rabin

I am looking for an implementation of the Rabin Hash Function in Java, Can anyone recommend a **fast** library?

---

Update:
I've just tested the library [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rabinhash/).

It takes ~2200ms to hash 1mm random urls on my 2GHz processor.

This is certainly good enough for my needs, however I will test another library when I get a monent and post the results here.

Comment: If there are some libraries that you've already tried, but they aren't fast enough, you might want to list them to avoid them being suggested to you again.

Comment: I've not tried any yet myself. But if i do any comparisons I'll post the results here.

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate your questions a bit more or provide links. I suppose you want to compute *Rabin fingerprints* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint)?

Comment: Pretty much yes. THe Rabin hash function allows you to produce hash functions with provably small co-incidence of collision between any two strings, proportional to 1/2^numkeydigits. There are few libraries that pop up when you do a google, i was simply wondering if anyone could recomend any of them from previous experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my Java implementation.

http://code.google.com/p/rabinfingerprint/

It also includes arbitrarily large irreducible polynomials (using BigIntegers).

Comment: Is there any c++ implementation/library for Robin Hash Function?     - Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I've not used it myself, but you can try the [Rabin Hash Function](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rabinhash/files/) project on Source Forge.

Comment: What do you know, the same project I recommended in my answer, which got deleted.

Comment: A LMGTFY link isn't a project recommendation.  It isn't an answer either, and it will always get deleted.

Comment: It's an excellent answer. It's certainly better than this one.

Comment: The majority of the SO community seems to disagree. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: I don't see a lot of agreement with your position at the link you provide.

Comment: @JF - the original question was a request for a "recommendation" for a "fast" library.